# How do I cope with lazy iterators?

Tags: rust, iterator, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to sort an array with a `map()` over an iterator.

```
struct A {
    b: Vec<B>,
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
struct B {
    c: Vec<i32>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A { b: Vec::new() };

    let b = B { c: vec![5, 2, 3] };
    a.b.push(b);

    a.b.iter_mut().map(|b| b.c.sort());
}
```

Gives the warning:

```
warning: unused `std::iter::Map` that must be used
  --> src/main.rs:16:5
   |
16 |     a.b.iter_mut().map(|b| b.c.sort());
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_must_use)] on by default
   = note: iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed
```

Which is true, `sort()` isn't actually called here. This warning is described in the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/iterators.html), but I don't understand why this variation with `iter_mut()` works fine:

```
a.b.iter_mut().find(|b| b == b).map(|b| b.c.sort());
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve. It's not clear what the `obj` variable's type is. Please provide a full MCVE that shows your error. Side-note: you should probably just do a `for o in &mut obj.numbers {}` and do your work in the loop

Comment: Sorry, I looked into the OP and found that I simplified to the point when it made no sense. Proper version is in the update.

Comment: You say "works fine" but it fetches the first element of the iterator and sorts it. Is it the desired result? `.next()` is a much clearer way of feching the first element, instead of using `.find()`.

Comment: No, I missed that part, it's not an intended behavior.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the book you linked to says:

> If you are trying to execute a closure on an iterator for its side effects, use `for` instead.

That way it works, and it's much clearer to anyone reading the code. You should use `map` when you want to transform a vector to a different one.

Comment: So `for b in a.b.iter_mut() { b.c.sort(); }` is the idiomatic way of doing this in Rust? I was under the impression that iterators should be used instead of for loops whenever possible.

Comment: Map is used when you have a vector and you want its contents in a different format without modifying the original vector. If you want to destructively modify the vector, you should use a loop.

Comment: @andreyg, yes, that would be the idiomatic way, and no, iterators should not be always used instead of for loops - this is not actually possible because iterators are lazy and for loop is not. You should use iterator transformers when appropriate, but if you need to process results in some non-standard way (e.g. when "terminal" operations like `fold()`, `find()` or others are not appropriate) you have to use `for` loop.

Comment: The for loop is a language feature that exists solely for use with iterators.

Answer (score 6):

> I don't understand why this variation with `iter_mut()` works fine:
>
> ```
> a.b.iter_mut().find(|b| b == b).map(|b| b.c.sort());
> ```

It works because `find` is not lazy; it's an iterator consumer. It returns an `Option` not an `Iterator`. This might be why it is confusing you, because `Option` also has a `map` method, which is what you are using here.

---

As others have said, `map` is intended for transforming data, without modifying it and without any other side-effects. If you really want to use `map`, you can map over the collection and assign it back:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = A { b: Vec::new() };
    let mut b = B { c: vec![5, 2, 3] };
    a.b.push(b);

    a.b =
        a.b.into_iter()
            .map(|mut b| {
                b.c.sort();
                b
            })
            .collect();
}
```

Note that vector's `sort` method returns `()`, so you have to explicitly return the sorted vector from the mapping function.

Answer (score 6):

I use [`for_each`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each). 
According to the doc:

> It is equivalent to using a `for` loop on the iterator, although `break` and `continue` are not possible from a closure. It's generally more idiomatic to use a `for` loop, but `for_each` may be more legible when processing items at the end of longer iterator chains. In some cases `for_each` may also be faster than a loop, because it will use internal iteration on adaptors like `Chain`.