# How do I get the index of the current element in a for loop in Rust?

Tags: loops, rust

I have a for loop:

```rust
let list: &[i32]= vec!(1,3,4,17,81);


for el in list {
 println!("The current element is {}", el);
 println!("The current index is {}", i);// <- How do I get the current index?
}
```

How can I get the index of the current element?

I have tried

`for el, i in list`

`for {el, i} in list`

`for (el, i) in list.enumerate()`

I was able to access the iterator using a map of the vec, but received an error:

```
unused `std::iter::Map` that must be used

note: `#[warn(unused_must_use)]` on by default
note: iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed
```

, and [this SO answer on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34766697/10235296) leads me to believe I should be using a for loop instead (though I could be misunderstanding), because I am not trying to adjust the original vec in any way.

Comment: Full error message please..

Comment: The tuple yielded by [`enumerate()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) is in reverse order, i.e. `(i, el)` and not `(el, i)`. See the [Examples section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#examples-13).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Just use [`enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate):

> Creates an iterator which gives the current iteration count as well as the next value.

```rust
fn main() {
    let list: &[i32] = &vec![1, 3, 4, 17, 81];

    for (i, el) in list.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("The current element is {}", el);
        println!("The current index is {}", i);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The current element is 1
The current index is 0
The current element is 3
The current index is 1
The current element is 4
The current index is 2
The current element is 17
The current index is 3
The current element is 81
The current index is 4
```

Comment: The `i` index variable here is usize, yes? Is there any way to enumerate with i32?

Comment: @NathanielFord See [`enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) *"`enumerate()` keeps its count as a `usize`. If you want to count by a different sized integer, the [`zip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip) function provides similar functionality."* - But why not `i as i32`?