# Splitting a Vec into Vecs according to condition

Tags: vector, rust, closures, match

I'm trying to split a Vec into 3 Vec depending on whether each i32 is positive, negative or non-negative.

```rust
let (mut n, mut p, mut z) = (Vec::new(), Vec::new(), Vec::new());

nums.iter() // returns &i32 for each num in nums
    .map(|num| { 
        match num == &0 { // if num == 0
            true => z.push(*num), // dereference it and push it to `z`, z means zero
            _ => match num > &0 {
                true => p.push(*num), // p means positive
                _ => n.push(*num) // n means negative
            }
        }
    }
    );

println!("p {:?}, n {:?}, z {:?}", p, n, z);
```

However, the output is that all 3 Vec are empty Vec.

```
p [], n [], z []
```

Why is that so? And how can I alter my codes such that I get 3 Vec which contains zero, positive and negative i32 in each?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I cope with lazy iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765967/how-do-i-cope-with-lazy-iterators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is giving you a warning:

```
warning: unused `Map` that must be used
  --> src/main.rs:5:5
   |
5  | /     nums.iter() // returns &i32 for each num in nums
6  | |         .map(|num| {
7  | |             match num == &0 {
8  | |                 // if num == 0
...  |
14 | |             }
15 | |         });
   | |___________^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_must_use)]` on by default
   = note: iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed
```

It is a good idea to pay attention to the compiler's warnings. In this case, the compiler is telling you the reason your code is not working: "iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed". `map()` just returns an iterator adapter, but unless you advance it, nothing happens.

You can add `.collect::<()>()` at the end of the `map()`, but it is better to just use a `for` loop:

```rust
for num in &nums {
    // returns &i32 for each num in nums
    match num == &0 {
        // if num == 0
        true => z.push(*num), // dereference it and push it to `z`, z means zero
        _ => match num > &0 {
            true => p.push(*num), // p means positive
            _ => n.push(*num),    // n means negative
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing `.map()` to `.for_each()` is another popular option.

Comment: @user4815162342 Per `for_each()` docs, "It’s generally more idiomatic to use a `for` loop, but `for_each` may be more legible when processing items at the end of longer iterator chains." This is not the case.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to change the answer, but providing an alternative. `for_each()` is very much present in Rust code bases, and a beginner should be aware of it.

Comment: I like @ChayimFriedman's answer but I tried to use `collect::<i32>()` at the end of `.map` to no avail:
```
nums.iter()
            .map(|num| {
                match num == &0 {
                    True => {z.push(*num);*num},
                    _ => match num > &0 {
                        True => {p.push(*num); *num},
                        _ => {n.push(*num); *num}
                        }
                    }
            })
            .collect::<i32>();
```
Output:
```
.collect::<i32>();
value of type `i32` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=i32>`

Comment: @JimChng I said `collect::<()>()`.

Comment: Beautiful, I tried it, works beautifully as intended.